# ENOSPC during npm run jest --watch

Tags: jestjs

After following the https://facebook.github.io/jest/#getting-started I successfully run tests and have fun, so go jest!

When I try to use the --watch feature I got a ENOSPC, but I have 2GB free.
Mmaybe he try to watch all my folders, including the dists and node_modules, is that the problem?

There is a way to tell to watch only specific directories?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly this is an issue with [watchmen](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html), which can be fixed by reinstall it using

```
$ brew update
$ brew install watchman
```

Comment: seems this didn't resolve my issue :( the situation remain the same

Comment: maybe you can post your jest settings from `package.json`

Comment: btw with watchman installed i got an additional error during normal jest execution saying that watchman was unable to apply inotify because I reach the user limit. I think we need to patch jest and exclude watching of the node_modules folder.

Comment: the node modules are excluded by default, expect you set `testPathIgnorePatterns` to some other folders and forgot to add `node_modules`